# Доступ к пустому полю в разреженной матрице

Tags: lua

Есть двумерный разреженный массив `matrix`. Доступ к элементу происходит следующим образом:

```
if matrix[x] and matrix[x][y] then
        -- Делаем что-то с этим элементом
end
```

При использовании `if matrix[x][y] then`, в случае, если по X нет массива, выдаёт ошибку `attempt to index a nil value`. Есть ли возможность решить эту проблему с помощью метатаблиц или ещё каким вариантом?

Comment: А чем не устраивает предварительная проверка  по `matrix[x]`?

Comment: Приходится писать одно и то же много раз. Одним местом чую, что есть способ проще

Comment: Оберните тогда эту проверку в функцию. Куда уж проще.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить определить метод вызова для получения данных:

```
setmetatable(matrix, {
    __call = function(self, x, y)
        result = self[x] == nil
        if result 
        then  
            return result 
        else  
            return self[x][y]
        end
    end,
})
```

Теперь если тебе нужно безопасно получить данные, ты можешь сделать так

```
content = matrix(x, y)
if content then
    ...
end
```